# In localhost when use I php artisan serve and npm run watch, output of url('/') is http://localhost:8000

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

In localhost when use

```
php artisan serve
```

and

```
npm run watch
```

output of 
 `url('/')` is `http://localhost:8000` but I expect it should be `http://localhost:3000` when the adderesbar of browser is http://localhost:3000.

Comment: Please update your question with your `.env` settings

Answer (score 4):

`npm run watch` is just looking for changes to your asset files for mix to rebuild them.

`php artisan serve` is what starts the php server.  The documentation indicates it will start the built-in php Local Development Server on port 8000: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

As far as the PHP script is concerned, that's how the request reaches it, which is why `url('/')` returns `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: but when use"npm run watch' the port by default is 3000
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#running-mix

Comment: @esmaeilsoomari `npm run watch` executes the Webpack asset compilation "watching" for when an asset source file changes to recompile it, it does not serve web pages. `artisan serve` is serving your web pages to the browser, which retrieves the post-compiled assets.

Comment: But in a controller when write dd(url('/')) it gives "localhost:3000"  and when write echo url('/'); die(); it gives "http://localhost:8000"; addresbar of browser is "http://localhost:3000".